# What was Count Dooku's first name?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, names

I've been searching the Internet for this for a long time, but couldn't find anything. Is his first name mentioned anywhere (maybe in the Expanded Universe)?

I've read some comments where people say his first name was Jard, but I can't find any official information about that.

Comment: count bobby dooku

Comment: I'd Argue that his first name would be Dooku. A noble wouldn't use their surname for their title because then everyone in the line would have the same name!

Comment: Dooku... James Dooku

Comment: @King_llama The general rule with Noble Titles is that if it's a Hereditary Title, then you are "Count [Surname]", or "Count [Surname] of [Location]".  If it is a Life Title then you are "Count [Location]".  In both cases, you can *also* be addressed as "[Forename], Count of [Location]".  Since he is "Count Dooku of Serrano", it's a hereditary title - I would *suspect* he was sent to the Jedi Temple in the same way that Second Sons were often sent to join the priesthood or a monastery in Europe, but something happened to his siblings and he was recalled ("an Heir and a Spare")

Comment: Oddly, back when he was just a Duke, he went by the name Countoo.

Comment: Marma Dooku. He doesn't like to talk about it.

Comment: Maybe Dooku was his first name, the same way that other nobles and royals go by their first name. We refer to the current British monarch as Queen *Elizabeth*, not Queen Windsor.

Answer (score 10):

### Count Dooku has not been given any additional name in any material, canon or Legends

As far as we know, his first name might be:

- "Count"
- [Nothing at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononymous_person)
- "[Slartibartfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slartibartfast)"
- "[Barry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102901/31051)"
- Something else entirely

### What about "Jard"?

As far as I can tell, the name "Jard" was created by noted fan [SuperShadow](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/SuperShadow), who claimed to be a close friend of George Lucas and posted many previously-unreleased tidbits and interviews on his website<sup>1</sup>; Dooku's name was one such fact, posted on the [FAQ section](https://web.archive.org/web/20060823010702/http://www.supershadow.com/starwars/frequently_asked_question.html) of his personal website.

Despite his claims, SuperShadow has no affiliation with George Lucas or Lucasfilm, and [has never been](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13597/31051) a source of legitimate canonical facts; everything on his website seems to have been invented by him. Many of the claims posted on his website were later contradicted by canon sources, and Pablo Hidalgo has publicly denounced the site.

---

<sup>1</sup> The website no longer exists, by the way; the supershadow.com domain is now owned by a Japanese company, and appears to point at a site advertising hair removal services

Comment: Thanks. I think it's most likely not revealed yet (and probably never will be) and I highly doubt 'Count' was his first name, that was his title; he was the Count of Serrano.

Comment: @HasanHadžić I agree, but I think it would be hilarious

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to buy Supershadow.com and rehost a copy of his old website, just for a laff.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think he had a last name. In our world if you were to say "Queen Elizabeth" or "President Donald" (even though it sounds off) people know what you mean. Of course both of these do have the last names of Windsor and Trump respectively, but if you look at the names of his family it always changes.  They may be different from my examples as they rule the planet and have only one ruler to speak of but I think Dooku is his first name.

[image: screenshot of "about" info on Dooku on the wikia]

Comment: Can you please [edit] to explain how the image is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

His last name is Serenno. The planet he comes from is named after his family (because they are the ruling family); this is based on the canon book *Dooku Jedi Lost*.

Comment: This is a nice find, can you [edit] in the relevant quote to back this up?

Comment: I think you'll find that he's referred to as Count Dooku *of* Serenno. It's not a surname but simply an indication of what he's Duke of. - "*Count Dooku of Serenno had been most responsible for bringing the galaxy’s disenfranchised worlds under one umbrella.*" [Tarkin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))